# How to make multiple instances of my graph chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/Lkdcw0em/5/ . Now I am trying to draw multiple such `graph charts` in a `single page` by passing the `data` and `div id` .It is drawing the `graphs` for me but the `left` and `right` `sliders` are not working .  How to make this. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I quite didn't understand your problem: you have everything ready. Just create another div id and call the function again. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ztaa5rca/

Comment: No its not working @GerardoFurtado . It will draw the graph for you . But the slider will not work

Comment: See in your fiddle , the upper graph sliders are not working

Comment: It's because of the scopes in JavaScript. It's working now: https://jsfiddle.net/03xm8oyL/ . Not perfect, the main problem here is that one slider gets the last value of the other, but you can improve this.

Comment: Correct @GerardoFurtado , i am also changing the same thanks for your help

Comment: It's better now, just linked it in the answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado still some improvements need to make , as the sliders are overlapping . They should not like original working copy. I am changing it. But your suggestion helped me . Thanks

Comment: I have fixed the slider not working/overlapping issue here https://jsfiddle.net/dibyendu/Lkdcw0em/6/. Basically the variables were conflicting hence sliders were not consistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript scope problem. Just put everything inside your `drawRangeSelector`function.

Here is the working JSFiddle (with another dataset for the 2nd chart): https://jsfiddle.net/s7ktLe1r/

Comment: if slider is not overlapping here, my modified copy still not working

Comment: It's not overlapping to me.

Comment: See added a screen , its overlapping actually

Comment: I can't reproduce your image. Besides that, this is *another* problem, not related with your original question. Please, don't edit your own questions to address a different problem